# How do I get a user's timezone info?

Tags: rest-api, timezone

What API call do I need to get a user's timezone? e.g. `"America/Los_Angeles"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to query the user table for the logged in user; it's located in the TimeZoneSidKey field.

The following query would probably work (assuming you change xxx to match the logged in user ID that you got when you logged in).

```
/services/data/v30.0/query?q=select%20id%2C%20timezonesidkey%20from%20user%20where%20id%20%3D%20'xxx'
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting a 404 though, using this `curl` command http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=yhTt7PEj. What did I do wrong?

Comment: user ID is the last part of this url, correct? `https://login.salesforce.com/id/00Dx0000000BV7z/005x00000012Q9P`

Comment: My instance url doesn't have v30.0 yet. Thanks!

Comment: You can use v29 instead. The 005 Id is the user id